# Unable to view USB stick/drive contents

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive

I plug-in my USB stick, copy a file from the hard drive to the USB stick, and safely remove the USB stick. I then plug out the USB stick.

When I plug the USB stick back into the computer again, the previous contents of the USB stick are all gone. It shows an empty drive.

I am using Windows XP SP2 with an 8 GB USB stick from Transcend.

Comment: Does the stick otherwise look like a functional drive?  What does Explorer's drive properties show about the stick's capacity and its used- and free-space?  Do those numbers make sense?

Comment: Does that happen every time you move a file to the drive, or did it just happen the one time?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a corrupted filesystem. run chkdsk on your usb stick or reformat it and see if that helps. If not it might be that the flash ram used in your usb stick is going bad.